# Use Count with aggregate(Sum) in django ORM, Custom Queryset Fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to use query in which I need No of Invoices and Total Amount of Invoices in a Queryset.

```
Invoice.objects.aggregate(total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount')) 
Invoice.objects.count()
```

How can I handle above queries in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of *distinct* primary keys:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

Invoice.objects.aggregate(
    total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount'),
    number_of_invoices=Count('pk', distinct=True)
)
```

This will return a dictionary with `'total_amount'` and `'number_of_invoices'` as keys.

Comment: and how can i use filter with this

Comment: @I'mSRJ: how are you filtering?

Comment: i want to filter like this ---> queryset.filter(order__owner=request.user) but your answer is returning dictionary then how can i do it.

Comment: ohk i got it---> Invoice.objects.filter(order__owner=request.user).aggregate(total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount'),number_of_invoices=Count('pk', distinct=True))          
 but is there a way that how can I get a queyset as your answer is returning dict